# Не отображается счетчик (JS)

Tags: javascript, html

Хочу поставить счетчик, идентичный как на сайте (*после таблицы идет подсчет денег ежесекундно*) [см. ссылку](https://www.wtfoot.com/player/lionel-messi/)
Собственно, нужно отобразить постоянно меняющиеся число. Мы его получаем путем умножения одного постоянного числа на секунду пребывания на сайте. Например:  при условии, что вы зарабатываете в секунду 1 доллар, будет отображаться счетчик, который с каждой секундой пребывания на сайте будет увеличиваться (типа, пока вы сюда смотрели, заработали ...n долларов) - просидели 10 секунд на странице - "*вы заработали 10 долларов*".

У меня следующий код. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку.

```js
var msSalary = parseFloat(4.02);
var startTime = new Date() / 1000;
calc();
        
function calc() {
    var timeNow = new Date() / 1000;
    var msSinceViewing = Math.ceil(timeNow - startTime);
    var wageSinceViewing = msSinceViewing * msSalary;
    document.getElementById('moneyclock').innerHTML = '$' + wageSinceViewing.toFixed(2);
    setTimeout(calc, 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="moneyclock"></div>
```

**Спасибо!**

Comment: Ну смотрите, на этом сайте есть функционал, который позволяет запускать код JS и HTML. Как видите, если его использовать, то ваш счетчик работает. Отсюда два вопроса: отображается ли какая-нибудь ошибка в консоли браузера и не выполняется ли ваш код раньше, чем прогружается остальная страница? Во втором случае достаточно перенести код JS после объявления `<div id="moneyclock"></div>`

Comment: Да, так и есть. Разместил вызов скрипта в самый низ документа - заработало. Спасибо Вам!